# Android calendar view?

Tags: android

Hi is their a calendar view component i can use to display the month week and day?

In j2me there was no such thing and we had to develop and implement one ourselves which was a pain and took months to complete

Answer (score 3):

There is a calendar view in the Google IO 2010 Conference app:
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/